# Personal Data on Work Computer

Tags: active-directory, security

I have a question. When using a computer at work one saves personal data as well. For example gmail accounts in the browser. Other credentials again in the browser or elsewhere. Also files from places like dropbox etc. There are plenty of legitimate reasons why these data may end up on a work computer.

The problem is that admins can reset your active directory password and then log into your pc and have full access to your accounts and logs. Even Skype accounts etc.

The obvious solution would be not to save anything in the browsers and not install dropbox (or create a work account for it) and log out from skype (which we use at work). But this is a lot of work. So is there any way to secure one's data against such a scenario?

**To avoid comments like the one below:**

I know whose property the computer is. However when the company asks you to use Skype and you do not want to create two accounts one for you and one for when you are at work or you don't want to create another dropbox account what do you do.

Comment: A work computer is your company's property, not yours. If you don't want them to access your data, don't put it on your work computer.

Comment: Don't conduct personal business on your work computer at work.

Comment: Re: your edit: you suck it up. Either be less paranoid (are your workplace admins really that interested in your Skype account) or deal with the inconvenience of different accounts.

Comment: The same idea still remains despite your edit. Realistically, you probably WANT to create/maintain multiple accounts. If you ever leave the company, you can leave the account for that company behind.

Comment: I closed this as too localized because your Local Laws will vary. Your IP indicates that you're not from the US, and most answers here are going to involve US laws (where anything on a computer becomes the property of the owner, the employer in most cases). Without involving a Lawyer there's no good way to answer this question for your case.

Comment: Consider two step authentication.  A lot of providers are adopting this (Gmail, Skype/MS).

Comment: I was going to say: then use an encrypted virtual machine and set all your personal stuffs there...

Comment: Chris S's answer is really important because as others have expressed the computer is the companies.  Personal data may or may not belong to the company as well (even in the US there is no uniform law on privacy) and it's not even clear if admins can legally perform the actions described above.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way: treat it like a public machine and set any site you visit to NOT save your credentials. You can do this with most websites (including Gmail). For Skype, disable auto-login on startup. Dropbox - just don't use it on your work computer.

In the end, it comes down to trust. If you can't *trust* your IT admins that they are professional and will not snoop in your personal data, then you have other things to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

> I know whose property the computer is. However when the company asks
>   you to use Skype and you do not want to create two accounts one for
>   you and one for when you are at work or you don't want to create
>   another dropbox account what do you do.

You have two choices:

1. Use your own accounts and open up the possibility of access to your employer
2. Create new accounts